# Getting an mysqli_connect function undefined in error log file of server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have an website when ever i try to access a certain page which brings data from the database i encounter an internal server error 500.When i check my log files of error it says 
`mysqli_connect() function undefined` 
Here is my code for connecting with the database

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gull");
if(!$connection){
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

and the code of page on which i am trying to fetch the data from database is as shown below.

```
<?php
$page = "typo";
include_once('admin/database.php');
include_once('include/header.php');
?><div class="breadcrumbs">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="breadcrumbs-main">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="index.php" style="color:#DAA520;">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="active">Behind the Scenes</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--typo-starts-->
        <div class="gallery">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="gallery-top heading">
                <h2 class="family">Behind the Scenes</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-bottom">
                <div class="row">
               <?php
          $select="select * from bti";
          $run=mysqli_query($connection,$select);
          while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)):
          ?>                  
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item" style="margin-top:1em;">
                <a href="bti/<?php echo $fetch['path'];?>" data-lightbox="<?php echo $fetch['path'];?>" data-title="">
                    <img class="img-responsive " src="bti/<?php echo $fetch['path'];?>" alt="" width="100%">
                </a>
            </div>
           <?php
           endwhile;
           ?>  



        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--typo-ends-->
    <!--footer-starts-->
    <?php
    include_once('include/footer.php');
    ?>
```

Is these some sort of server error or is there any fault within my code?

Comment: mysqli extension doesn't installed in your server. check phpinfo();

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ already tried but site is showing me an blank page!!

Comment: Do u get a blank page when u just run phpinfo(); ? Make a clear page. just put phpinfo(); in it. There's no way to get a blank page with phpinfo o.0

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ already tried that .. here is the link of the page http://sukoongulati.com/text.php and the code is here <?php
phpinfo();
?> the same code runs on localhost but on these server

Comment: the problem is solved out...it was an error at the data center that is what told me by the hosting provider so i am posting these answer here so it may help other guys in future thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved out...it was an error at the data center that is what told me by the hosting provider so i am posting these answer here so it may help other guys in future thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

**Note: These instructions are for Windows**

If the function `mysqli_connect()` is not present, it's because the [MySQLi extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is not enabled in your PHP installation.  To enable it, do the following:

**1.** Find the location of your `php.ini` file.  Execute:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
exit;
```

Lookup the row `Loaded Configuration File` and note the path to your configuration file. That's the `php.ini`

**2.** Open the configuration file in any text editor and run a search for `php_mysqli`.  You should find a line similar to:

```
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Uncomment that line, by removing the semi-colon `;` in front of it.

**3.** Restart your webserver

Once everything is in place, the `phpinfo()` output should have a MySQLi section that shows it's enabled:
[image]

Comment: When you downvote, leave a comment so I can improve my answer if I agree.

Comment: How do you know he's running Windows?

Comment: @Machavity I don't. Why do you ask? Doesn't my answer make it clear that the file name would be different depending on OS?

Comment: The install method for Linux flavors is VERY different from Windows. Your advice is only applicable to Windows

Comment: @Machavity thank you. I've added a clear note to that effect. If downvoters with the right idea make it a habit to leave their reasons, those answerers who want to help the OP will generally improve or delete their answer and SO will be better for it.

Comment: Good answer because you specified the operating system and the way you described it was pretty straight forward. Thanks. I could not of explained it better myself.

Comment: Here's the down vote reason: OP commented 2 hours before you wrote "already tried that .. here is the link of the page sukoongulati.com/text.php and the code is here <?php phpinfo(); ?> the same code runs on localhost but on these server "  Prolly phpinfo() command blocked on server. And it's shared server so he hasn't access to ssh. basicly he hasn't a way to access php.ini.

Comment: And yes, the answer is he hasn't installed mysqli extension so he has to write his code on PDO.